# Keyboard repeat rate is very slow in MinGW (Git Bash)

Tags: windows, keyboard, git-bash, msys2

I'm using the highest *Keyboard Repeat Rate* setting in Windows. Recently I've found that something slows down this repeat rate in MinGW (Git Bash) on one of my computers.

I've tested keyboard speed on 3 computers: Windows 7 personal, Windows 10 personal, Windows 10 work. Both personal computers are consistent: the highest repeat rate gives the highest speed in every application (I've tried *Notepad*, *cmd*, *Git Bash*), and this rate is close to 300 characters per 10 seconds. Just for experiment I've tried the slowest rate: it gives 25 characters per 10 seconds.

Now the turn of the Windows 10 work laptop. It gives the same results for slowest rate (25 characters per 10 seconds in every application), and the highest rate in *Notepad* and *cmd* (a little less than 300 characters per 10 seconds). *Git Bash* is the exception: almost twice as slow for the highest settings. As I can see, that is not the matter of scalability: the same speed rate is observed for the middle speed setting in Windows Keyboard Properties. So looks like there is something that limits Git Bash to provide the highest Repeat Rate. What that could be and how to fix that? Is there any setting? Are there hooks on keypresses?

Comment: I get the same rate as you on my Windows 10 laptop: 30 characters per second.  My guess would be that there is some virus scanner or other type of software on your work laptop that somehow slows down the processing that MinTTY and/or bash does for each keystroke, and it slows it down by tens of milliseconds.

Comment: @DavidGrayson why doesn't that slow down other applications then?